# Rewriting switch program to if else

Tags: c, if-statement

In one of my problem sets I need to rewrite a program that has switches into if/else statements.

The program is to tally the grades entered, so if I enter "a" it will tally that, and when I exit the program it will give the user a final tally of all the grades that were entered.

I have two problems, the first one is it's simply not working, it's not reading the character inputs as legitimate characters that I have set. The second is how to prevent the other if statements from executing after the correct one executes.

I have it set as breaks in the if/else statements. I'm not sure if they are working because the program obviously isn't even accepting the characters.

I was going to have them be goto, but the original program had breaks so I used them instead.

```
{
int grade;
int aCount=0;
int bCount=0;
int cCount=0;
int dCount=0;
int fCount=0;

puts( "Enter the letter grades" );
puts( "Enter EOF to end input" );

while( ( grade = getchar() ) != EOF )
    {

        if( grade == 'A' && grade == 'a' )
        {
            ++aCount;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "%s\n", "That's not a valid grade, please enter again" );
            break;
        }

        if( grade == 'B' && grade == 'b' )
        {
            ++bCount;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "%s\n", "That's not a valid grade, please enter again" );
            break;
        }

        if( grade == 'C' && grade == 'c' )
        {
            ++cCount;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "%s\n", "That's not a valid grade, please enter again" );
            break;
        }

        if( grade == 'D' && grade == 'd' )
        {
            ++dCount;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "%s\n", "That's not a valid grade, please enter again" );
            break;
        }

        if( grade == 'F' && grade == 'f' )
        {
            ++fCount;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "%s\n", "That's not a valid grade, please enter again" );
            break;
        }
    }

puts( "\nTotals for each letter grade are:" );
printf( "A: %d\n", aCount );
printf( "B: %d\n", bCount );
printf( "C: %d\n", cCount );
printf( "D: %d\n", dCount );
printf( "F: %d\n", fCount );

return 0;
```

}

Comment: You need to chain your conditions with `else if` and finish the chain with `else` reporting the error.

Comment: When would you expect `grade == 'A' && grade == 'a'` to be true?

Comment: Although we can guess what your original `switch` version looks like, it is still helpful to include it in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it's syntactically correct to use break inside an if statement, it's confusing because it's really breaking out of the enclosing while statement. Something like this is closer to what you're looking for:

```
puts( "Enter EOF to end input" );

while( ( grade = getchar() ) != EOF ) {
    if( grade == 'A' || grade == 'a' )
        ++aCount;
    else if( grade == 'B' || grade == 'b' )
        ++bCount;
    else if( grade == 'C' || grade == 'c' )
        ++cCount;
    else if( grade == 'D' || grade == 'd' )
        ++dCount;
    else if( grade == 'F' || grade == 'f' )
        ++fCount;
    else
        printf( "That's not a valid grade, please enter again\n" );
}

puts( "\nTotals for each letter grade are:" );
printf( "A: %d\n", aCount );
printf( "B: %d\n", bCount );
printf( "C: %d\n", cCount );
printf( "D: %d\n", dCount );
printf( "F: %d\n", fCount );

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think it is silly to have a variable for each grade. How about the examining board wants to add another grade? Seems a lot of effort when an array could do the job a lot easier.

Comment: Agreed, although the question was about how to emulate the logic of a switch/case statement using if/else. More of a contrived homework example than real code, I presume.

Answer (score 2):

You should change the AND (&&) conditions to be OR (||) conditions so that either 'A' OR 'a' increments the `aCount` variable. Use a large `if` - `else if` - `else` chain to prevent the repeated error check. The error print statement can be simplified by using just a string literal.

```
if (grade == 'A' || grade == 'a') {
    ++aCount;
} else if (grade == 'B' || grade == 'b') {
    ++bCount;
} else if (grade == 'C' || grade == 'c') {
    ++cCount;
} else if (grade == 'D' || grade == 'd') {
    ++dCount;
} else if (grade == 'F' || grade == 'f') {
    ++fCount;
} else {
    printf("That's not a valid grade, please enter again");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your conditions cannot be true at the same time. Change them to OR ( || )

```
if( grade == 'D' && grade == 'd' )
```

grade cannot be both D and d

Comment: This correctly points out a problem, but it doesn't answer the whole question. It doesn't address "[preventing] the other `if` statements from executing after the correct one executes."

Comment: The conditions need properly organising. `if(){} elseif(){} elseif(){} else(){}`. They execute logically so "if" the first expression is true execute it "else if" the next is true execute that, and so on, "else" none are true so execute that.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just store the grades in an array?

i.e.

```
int grades[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
while( ( grade = getchar() ) != EOF )
    grade = toupper(grade);
    if (grade >= 'A' && grade <= 'E') {
        ++grades[grade - 'A']; 
    } else {
        printf("That's not a valid grade, please enter again\n");
    }
 }
```